# Vaults secrets injected by vault sidecar container inside the pod are visible to kubernetes cluster users/admin

Tags: security, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have integrated the external vault into kubernetes cluster. Vault is injecting the secrets into shared volume “/vault/secrets” inside the pod which can be consumed by application container. Till now everything looks good.

But I can see security risk by inserting the secrets into shared volume in plain text as anyone can access the application secrets who has access to the kubernetes cluster.

Example: Secrets are injected into shared volume at **/vault/secrets/config**

Now, If kubernetes cluster admin logged in and he can access the pod along with credentials available at the shared volume in plain text format.

Kubectl exec -it <pod> command will be used to enter into pod.

In this case, my concern is cluster admin can access the application secrets (Ex: database passwords) which is security risk. In my scenario vault admin is different and kubernetes cluster admin is different.

Comment: You would probably prefer to have the applications authorized to access the credentials themselves with individual policies instead of using the sidecar. This would also minimize other security risks.

Comment: Are you saying, we can avoid using vault agent sidecar? Can you please elaborate on individual policies approach.

Answer (score 0):

Having a shared volume available to all pods in a cluster where all the secrets are stored in plain-text doesn't sound too secure to be honest. You could improve the securtity a little bit (only a little bit) by defining the use-limit (num_uses token attribute) to 1 (one) and alerting whenever legitimate application (that is the one that the secret was intended for) gets token invalid error messege.
I'm a K8s noob but how about this guide:
https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/integrating-hashicorp-vault-in-openshift-4
I know it's for RH OSE but maybe the concept sparks an idea.